# Best puzzles of 2019 Q4 (October - December)?

Tags: discussion, best-of

*This question is part of the [best-puzzle award series](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of).*

---

> What are your nominations for the best puzzles, here on Puzzling.SE, of the fourth quarter ( October / November / December ) 2019?
>
> ---

Suggested guidelines for nomination:

- Nominate each individual puzzle in a separate answer, so they can be upvoted/downvoted separately.
- No more than 3 nominations per person.
- Don't nominate your own puzzles.
- Before you nominate a puzzle, check to see if someone else has already nominated it. If they have, then add to that nomination as a comment (or edit it) instead of nominating the same puzzle again.
- **In your nomination, explain what it is that (in your opinion) makes the nominated puzzle such a good one.**

---

Some lists to help jog your memory (your nomination doesn't have to be from these lists):

> **Algorithmically selected "best of"**:
>
> - [***Popular puzzles***, both in score and in vote to view ratio, from 2019 Q4](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/509699/popular-puzzles-quaterly?year=2019&month=10#query-results)
> - [Well received puzzles ***you may have missed*** from 2019 Q4](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/871694/puzzles-you-may-have-missed-quaterly?year=2019&month=10#query-results)
>
> **Best by votes/views:**
>
> - [Questions with the most ***votes*** from 2019 Q4](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106579?StartDate=2019/10/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the most ***views*** from 2019 Q4](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106705?StartDate=2019/10/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the highest-voted ***answers*** from 2019 Q4](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106709?StartDate=2019/10/01#query-results)

---

<sub>Meta-meta issues:</sub>

- <sub>Is this kind of thing allowed on SE?</sub>

  - <sub>Yes, [Photography SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) and [Sci-fi/Fantasy SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3142/31394) do something very similar.</sub>
- <sub>What's the point?</sub>
- <sub>To highlight and encourage good practice in a way that goes beyond upvotes.</sub>
- <sub>To work towards building a 'hall of fame' of some of the best puzzles on the site (perhaps to reside on a future puzzling.SE blog) - think of it as our 'greatest hits album'.</sub>
- <sub>To prompt members to put forward their own reflections on what makes a high-quality puzzle.</sub>

Comment: I thought it was time we caught up on the past few instalments of this thread! Reading the 'Best puzzles of...' posts really helped me get into Puzzling as a community and appreciate what makes a well-received puzzle on this site. I think we would all benefit as a community by bringing this to mind again. (I will now launch the next two of these posts as well...)

Comment: I really want some answers here... come on, fellow puzzlers! I wasn't around at this point but most of you were.

Answer (score 3):

## [This new puzzle type needs a name](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92013/this-new-puzzle-type-needs-a-name) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv)

This one must have been a massive amount of work to pull off. It fits together two rather restrictive logic puzzle types into a single large grid, using clever visuals to hint at possible steps to be taken next. The puzzle became a big hit, being one of the most upvoted questions of 2019, and launched a <strike>million-dollar</strike> thousand-rep [puzzle franchise](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=needs+a+name+user%3A60644). It has inspired [several](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/95216/puzzle-needs-a-name) [other](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94399/pandiagonal-magic-takuzu) [mashups](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101493/this-stylization-needs-a-name) of different puzzle types by other users. Stiv's thorough self-answer detailing the creation process makes it all the more informative and interesting for fellow puzzlers.